# Null Object Pattern - public static final

Tags: java, design-patterns

I saw sometime in the last month an implementation of Null Object pattern as what seemed like a Singleton field on a type. I can't really remember the approach though. I'm working on patterns and conscious of implementing them out of place.

From my mind I think it would be as follows but can I get a review on that?

```java
public final class SearchCriteriaAnomalyFilter {

   public static final SearchCriteriaAnomalyFilter NULL_INSTANCE;

   private final T2AnomalyStatus status;
   private final T2AnomalyType type;
   private final boolean limitMaxOneAnomaly;

   public SearchCriteriaAnomalyFilter(T2AnomalyStatus status, T2AnomalyType type, 
                                          boolean limitMaxOneAnomaly){
       this.status = status;
       this.type = type;
       this.limitMaxOneAnomaly = Boolean.valueOf(limitMaxOneAnomaly);
   }

   private SearchCriteriaAnomalyFilter(){}

   public static SearchCriteriaAnomalyFilter instanceOfNullObject(){
      if (NULL_INSTANCE == null) {
         NULL_INSTANCE = new SearchCriteriaAnomalyFilter();   
      }
      return NULL_INSTANCE;
   }

    ...
}
```

Comment: What about the first constructor ? Not needed ?

Comment: It seems to me that I can statically initialise it by `instanceOf` or by creating an instance - which may be me mixing two concepts ie immutability and null object

Comment: Ask it here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I had the thought that I needed two types: a correcty initialised type or a null object

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - Ah... my editor is explaining to me what you mean. No argument constructor is maybe unneccessary

Comment: @Crowie Seems ok to me.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Yes I see now the necessity. Have had to initialise final fields in the no-arg private constructor too

Comment: @Crowie Yes, that is what I wondered before. Glad, you recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static final SearchCriteriaAnomalyFilter NULL_INSTANCE = new SearchCriteriaAnomalyFilter(); 
public static SearchCriteriaAnomalyFilter instanceOfNullObject(){
  return NULL_INSTANCE;
}
```

The rest of your code seemed fine.

The reason to use the above construct is that there is no need for a lazy initialization: the null-object won't change, nor does it need any special construction (as you properly implemented with the private constructor).

Comment: Makes sense cheers. A few red-lines in my IDE have insisted my final fields be initialised. I don't know the defaults for now so I've set them to `null` and false as needed. Ironic and potentially credibility reducing. I had better investigate some defaults.

Comment: You're welcome. It's better to ask a good question, then to implement a bad solution. ;)